# Array Extend without custom method?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use `Array.push` to add multiple values from a list? For example, currently what I'm having to do is:

```js
Array.prototype.extend = function(arr) {
    for (let elem of arr) {
        this.push(elem);
    }
}
let x = [1,2,3];
let y = [4,5,6];
let z = [7,8,9];
x.push(y);
x.extend(z)
console.log(x);
```

Or, is there some way to pass the array as a single argument to the `push` method, or perhaps there's another Array method entirely that does this instead?

Comment: `x.push.apply(x, y);`

Comment: @Pointy that's pretty neat -- could you please explain how that works a bit?

Comment: @David542 `x.push` returns a `[object Function]`. `Function.prototype.apply` receives `this` and an argument list.

Comment: The `.apply()` method on the Function prototype takes two arguments: the value to be used for `this`, and an array. The array is treated as the function argument list. In modern JavaScript, it's the same as `x.push(... y)`, which I'd use if I didn't have to worry about Internet Explorer.

Comment: `x.push(...y)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually bad practice to [Extend Native Types with Custom Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice). So instead of adding custom ones to the Array prototype you could:

- **Push** values of another Array using the [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...`

```js
const x = [1,2,3];
const y = [4,5,6];
const z = [7,8,9];
x.push(y);
x.push(...z)
console.log(x);
```

- **Concatenate**, using the [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
let x = [1,2,3];
const y = [4,5,6];
const z = [7,8,9];
x.push(y);
x = x.concat(z);
console.log(x);
```

The difference being - `.concat()` does not directly modify the original Array, therefore the `x = x.concat(` assignment syntax, and the Original `x` array being set as a [`let` variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

Comment: As you realized though, `Array.prototype.concat()` isn't mutational, so you have to manually re-assign the value to the array.

Comment: Thank you @code exactly as you pointed out, and clearly visible from the `x = x.concat` - Added the respective `let` and `const` to make it more obvious.

Comment: @code yes yes! Added a paragraph to make it textually more explicit :)

Answer (score 1):

You can push multiple arguments to `Array.prototype.push` and they'll all be pushed to our result array, so we can "convert" our array into multiple arguments using the ES6 spread syntax.

```js
let x = [1,2,3];
let y = [4,5,6];
x.push(...y);
console.log(x);
```

Comment: yes except it's not an operator; it's not part of the expression grammar.

Comment: @Pointy then what would it be? Google search "javascript spread" and (besides, coincidentally, MDN) all the results' titles are "spread operator - [...]".

Comment: It's part of JavaScript *syntax*, but like the `return` or `while` keywords, it's not an operator. An operator is a symbol like `+` or `*` or `[ ]` etc that figures into the expression grammar of a language. It's kind-of splitting hairs, but it really isn't an "operator".

Comment: Terminology is annoying, but it's important. It's why surgeons and nurses know the names of all the tools, so that a doctor doesn't have to say "hand me the little squeezy thing".

Answer (score 1):

you can spread the array element like this

```
const x = [1,2,3];
const y = [4,5,6];
const z = [7,8,9];
x.push(...y);
x.push(...z)
console.log(x);
```